# Leer un archivo con Java Web Start (jnlp)

Tags: java, java-ee, aplicación-web

Tengo una aplicación en java que lee un archivo config.db, de forma local funciona correctamente pero al ejecutarlo desde jnlp me dice que no existe ese archivo, de la misma forma y caso se dan con los reportes *.jasper config.properties etc.

PD: todos los archivos y librerías ya cuentan con permiso o llave.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @JoeBlack. Por favor agrega más información sobre el problema para que podamos reproducirlo o para comprender más el contexto de lo que te sucede, de ese modo te podremos ayudar más en la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo JNLP deberás poner las referencias tengo entendido.

En la documentación viene como incluirlas, probablemente si estas usando Netbeans o algún IDE similar, al compilar las bibliotecas te las localiza en una carpeta llamada lib.

Documentación al respecto.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html